# Is there a way to know when allocated nodes become available in Slurm?

Tags: slurm

[sinfo](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sinfo.html) only shows the current status (`alloc`, `idle`, etc) and a time limit of Slurm nodes.
[squeue](https://slurm.schedmd.com/squeue.html) seems only to show the jobs submitted by a user themselves, but not the jobs submitted by other users.

Is there a way to know when the nodes allocated by other users would become available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to know when the nodes allocated by other users would become available?

The only reliable way would be to submit a job. Then Slurm can warn you by email with `--mail-type=BEGIN`.

Note that `sbatch` has a `--test-only` argument that tells you when your job would run if submitted, without actually submitting a job.

Also, `srun` has an `--immediate` argument that allows submitting and job and cancelling it if it does not get an allocation within a few seconds. `sbatch` has a similar parameter `--deadline`

Finally, if you need an interactive session and be available when the job starts, you can submit a job with `--begin`. For instance if you want to have an interactive session at the same time the next day, submit a job the day before (assuming reasonable job length) with `--begin=now+24hours`